# Elasticsearch top_hits aggregation vs latest document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, kibana-6

I am trying to get a list of users who has as their last activity "connect". Ideally, I want this as a metric viz or a data table in Kibana showing the number of users that connected last and the list of them, respectively. I have, however, given up being able to do this in Kibana. I can get something similar directly from Elasticsearch using a terms aggregation followed by top_hits as below. But the problem is, even though I am sorting the top_hits by @timestamp, the resulting document in NOT the most recent.

```
{
"size" : 0,
"sort": { "@timestamp": {"order": "desc"} },
"aggs" : {
    "by_user" : {
    "terms" : { 
            "field" : "fields.username.keyword",
            "size" : 1
        },
        "aggs": {
            "last_message": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "_source": {
                        "includes": ["fields.username.keyword", "@timestamp", "status"]
                    },
                    "size": 1
                }
            }
        }
        }
}
}
```

1. Is there a way to do this directly in Kibana?
2. How can I make sure top_hits gives me the *latest* results, rather than the "most relevant"?

Comment: Do you want a list of the last connect events (and the same user could appear multiple times in that list) or should there be only one event per user (the very last one)?

Comment: I only need the very last event, hence the size:1 in the top_hits aggregation. The idea is to list the users whos last event was a connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-collapse.html), which is faster than an aggregation.

Something like this should work for your use case:

```
GET my-index/_search {
    "query": {
        "match_all": { }
    },
    "collapse" : {
        "field" : "fields.username.keyword" 
    },
    "sort": [ {
        "@timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
    } ] }
```

I might be missing something, but I don't think Kibana supports this at the moment.